# The QR code doesnot work for WhatsApp web. What is the issue?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

While I click on the whatsapp web from menu , it opens scanner but can't read the code. Why?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The device you're using, Android version it is running. Also check and update the tags you've used to match your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is Most probably due to the bandwidth of either Computer or Mobile me too have faced the issue when i had a bad bandwidth as the WhatsApp web changes its QR in a very short period of time within which the Android should capture it and process it online I'll prefer you to connect your mobile in wifi and try the same :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried to scan it in portrait rather than landscape mode and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

It could happen if you're using high contrast theme on Windows. If that's the case, then just set the theme to Windows Basic theme and it will work.

I regularly do it because I use black contrast theme.